# Video Recording with AVCaptureSession Doesn't Save Any Video

Tags: ios, ios8, avcapturesession

I am attempting to record video and save it to file using AVCaptureSession. I am using a singleton to handle my capture session, as there are several VCs in my app where I'm displaying a video preview.

The video preview displays correctly, but when I attempt to record video everything appears to work and I get no errors however when I look at the app container, no video files have been saved.

Here are the relevant functions from my Capture Session code

```
-(void)recordVideoSetup{
    // Code adapted from
    // www.ios-developer.net/iphone-ipad-programmer/development/camera/record-video-with-avcapturesession-2

    NSLog(@"Adding Movie File Output");

    MovieFileOutput = [[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput alloc] init];

    Float64 TotalSeconds = 600; // 10 minutes max
    int32_t preferredTimeScale = 30; //fps
    CMTime maxDuration = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(TotalSeconds, preferredTimeScale); // Set Max Duration

    MovieFileOutput.maxRecordedDuration = maxDuration;
    MovieFileOutput.minFreeDiskSpaceLimit = 1024*1024*10; // 10 MB

    if ([captureSession canAddOutput:MovieFileOutput]) {
        NSLog(@"Added output to capture session");
        [captureSession addOutput:MovieFileOutput];
    }


    AVCaptureConnection *CaptureConnection = [MovieFileOutput connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    // SET LANDSCAPE ORIENTATION
    if ([CaptureConnection isVideoOrientationSupported]) {
        AVCaptureVideoOrientation orientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight;
        [CaptureConnection setVideoOrientation:orientation];
    }


    NSLog(@"Setting image quality");
    [captureSession setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium];
    if ([captureSession canSetSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480])
        [captureSession setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480];

}

-(NSURL*)startRecordingVideo:(NSString *)surveyID {
    DDLogCInfo(@"Video Recording Started");

    // Get URL to record to

    NSString *documentsDirPath =[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject];
    documentsDirPath = [documentsDirPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"video"];
    NSURL *documentsDirUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:documentsDirPath isDirectory:YES];
    NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.mp4", surveyID];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:filename relativeToURL:documentsDirUrl];

    DDLogCInfo(@"Path to video: %@", url.path);

    NSFileManager *filemanager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ([filemanager fileExistsAtPath:[documentsDirPath stringByAppendingString:filename]]) {
        NSError *error;
        if ([filemanager removeItemAtURL:url error:&error] == NO) {
            DDLogCError(@"Could not record video");
            return nil;
        }
    }

    [MovieFileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:url recordingDelegate:self];

    return url;
}

-(void)stopRecordingVideo {
    DDLogCInfo(@"Video Recording Ended");
    [MovieFileOutput stopRecording];

}


-(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureFileOutput *)captureOutput didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:(NSURL *)outputFileURL fromConnections:(NSArray *)connections error:(NSError *)error {

    // Check if Recording was successfull

    BOOL recordedSuccessfully = YES;

    if ([error code] != noErr) {
        NSLog(@"A Problem occurred with recording");

        // A Problem Occurred
        id value = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:AVErrorRecordingSuccessfullyFinishedKey];
        if (value) {
            recordedSuccessfully = [value boolValue];
        }
    }

    if (!recordedSuccessfully) {
        DDLogCInfo(@"!!! - VIDEO RECORDING ERROR");
    }

}
```

EDIT: Some additional info
This is the log output I get:

```
SafeCurveSpeed[9060:3691230] Adding Movie File Output
SafeCurveSpeed[9060:3691230] Added output to capture session
SafeCurveSpeed[9060:3691230] Setting image quality
SafeCurveSpeed[9060:807] Video Recording Started
SafeCurveSpeed[9060:807] Path to video: "/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/44A52ADB-0E36-4303-9DE3-99E9CCCAF3FC/Documents/video/survey-video-10.mp4"
SafeCurveSpeed[9060:807] Video Recording Ended
```

EDIT 2: 
I've added a method to observe "AVCaptureSessionRuntimeErrorNotification" Notifications, but none fired during 'recording'. I've also added a log call to the top of the `captureOutput didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:` method, and found that it did not reach that method at all after recording had finished. Still unsure of the cause though.

Comment: I was able to get video recording to work, unfortunately by no longer using a singleton to manage the capture session, sacrificing the camera preview in my main menu's UI. It seems that using capture session in this way was not allowing video to be recorded properly.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code after 
Path to video:

```
UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(url.path, self, @selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
```

Add this method in VC

```
- (void)video:(NSString *)videoPath didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo: (void *) contextInfo {
    if (error == nil) {
       [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Saved to camera roll" message:@"" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
    } else {
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Failed to save" message:error.localizedDescription delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
    }
}
```

Use this third party library

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/screcorder

https://github.com/rFlex/SCRecorder

http://www.ios-developer.net/iphone-ipad-programmer/development/camera/record-video-with-avcapturesession-2

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. In my app I'm not trying to save anything to the camera roll, rather I already have a video preview in my VC, as it forms a part of the UI, but I would like to record video at the same time, and save it to file within the app bundle, as the URL is saved in a core data entity so the video can be fetched and played at a later time.